# Issue creating a Form with steps / groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I have two main sections `intro-info` and `current-info`. I essentially want them to do the same thing, but show at different times. On page load, the `intro-info` container shows first and you go through and fill the inputs and then click proceed. The thing I cannot figure out is how to display the `current-info` container, but hide all inputs other than the first after clicking the button.

I am hiding the first container, `intro-info`, by using `.hide()` and then showing it with `show()`. Like this:

```
$('#intro-button').click(function(){
    $('#intro-info').hide(200);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#current-info').show(500);
    }, 300);
});
```

In the show line, I have tried doing, `$('.current)`, `$('.current:first-child)`, but nothing shows up when I do it and ideally I want the entire container to appear for future additions, but simply hide all inputs other than the first one.

[Here is a fiddle to show you what I mean](https://jsfiddle.net/2o8Lxuo3/) ... Again, right after you hit proceed, once all of the inputs are filled in, you will see  the section section come into view and more than one input. Does anyone see what I can do?

Comment: Be careful using `this.value.trim() !== "";` it's ES5 and lacks older browser support. Using jQuery? Stick to jQuery! `$.trim(this.value) !== "";`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks for the heads up

Comment: If you want to get first child of another selector you can use `:nth-child()` selector. 

Example: `$( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).something()`

Comment: @Becky so basically you want the *second set* to behave exactly like did the first one (show "labels" one-by-one), right?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes...exactly.

Comment: @Becky I suggest you to not copy-paste code that dose something you already wrote. Remove those useless IDs and extra classes. Use some logic like: 1. one parent has one proceed button - on click show next parent element. 2. Every input makes appear the next input in the same parent.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm still really new to JS...not sure how to do it anyway else.

Comment: @Becky added an example of how I'd do it. Notice the simpler HTML, CSS and a better jQuery (Now you can have hundreds of groups without copy/pasting JS all over the place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said in my comments, I'd not create copy/paste - spaghetti code,
Instead I'd stick to a better logic:

remove those useless IDs and extra classes. Use some logic like: 1. one parent has one proceed button - on click show next parent element. 2. Every input makes appear the next input in the same parent.

```js
jQuery(function( $ ) { // DOM is now ready

  // Group your logic by parents!
  $(".labelsGroup").each(function() {

    var $thatGroup = $(this);
    var $nextGroup = $thatGroup.next(".labelsGroup");
    var $inputs    = $thatGroup.find("input");
    var $proceed   = $thatGroup.find("button");

    $inputs.on("input", function(){
      var $nextLabel = $(this).closest("label").next("label");
      if($.trim(this.value).length > 3) {
        $nextLabel.has(":input").addClass("show");
      }
    });

    $proceed.on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // Don't submit <form> (if any is used)
      
      var allValid = $inputs.filter(function() { 
        return $.trim(this.value).length > 3;
      }).length === $inputs.length;
      // TODO: use a better validation plugin than the above

      if(allValid) { // Finally proceed!!
        $thatGroup.addClass("hide");
        $nextGroup.addClass("show");
        // TODO: Submit form using AJAX to a service
      } else {       // or Log error!!
        return alert("Please fill-in the missing fields!");
      }

    });

  });
});
```

```css
.labelsGroup {
  text-align: center;
}
.labelsGroup label {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.labelsGroup label input {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
/* hide all but first label in parent */
/* hide all subsequent labelsParents */
.labelsGroup label + label,
.labelsGroup + .labelsGroup,
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
  position: relative !important;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="labelsGroup">
  <label>
    What is your name?<br>
    <input name="name" type="text"><!-- PS: use name="" instead of id=""-->
  </label>
  <label>
    What is your email address?<br>
    <input name="email" type="email">
  </label>
  <label>
    <button>Proceed</button>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="labelsGroup">
  <label>
    Do you have<br>
    <input name="have" type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    What is your current<br>
    <input name="what_is_your" type="text">
  </label>
  <label>
    <button>Proceed</button>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect! Two quick questions. Since I am having these seperate containers hide and show, would it be better to validate before I proceed with the button to the next container? Secondly, why use names instead of id's?

Answer (score 0):

You need to target every element with the class `intro` and include the 1st occurrence ( using `:first` ) of that element in the DOM

```
$('#intro-button').click(function(){
    $('#intro-info').hide(); // hide intro-info div
  $("#current-info").show(); // show current-info
  $('.current').hide(); // hide all elements with class current
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.current:first').show(200); // display once the 1st occuring element 
    }, 300);
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/2o8Lxuo3/3/

Comment: I want everything from `intro-info` to hide. The issue is the show for the `current-info`. I want only the container to show and the first input.

Comment: That sort of works, but isn't the `.note(":first")` excluding the container? It loads everything first and then hides it. Is there a different way?

Comment: That's wrong. The proceed button is also jumpy and promotes copy/paste spaghetti code...

Comment: I had multiple versions of the fix in my mind. Didn't realize the bumpy version. Replaced with a better one.